# How to properly typeset a box with a list of text

Tags: tables, text

I currently set up a box the normal way which got me look like this
[image]

as you can see the problem I have is that my text extends beyond the margin. What I want looks something like this

[image]

where the width of the box is as wide as the column of the two-column format, and the text within the box also automatically does a linebreak.

Edit:
My code looks like this

```
\begin{table}[ht]
%\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
 % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
\textbf{The protocol} \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
%heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\centering
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Draw a random sequence of \textbf{G} = $\{U_{r}\}_{r=1,...,|\textbf{G}|}$ that what about with more words
\end{enumerate}
& 50 & 837 & 970 \\ [1ex]% inserting body of the table % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: @Bernard, please see my edit above!

Comment: In your table, you only define one column, but use four inside of your table. This will result in error messages such as `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

Comment: You might be interested in using `tabularx` and its `X` type column in order to automatically make a table as wide as a define width.

Answer (score 1):

First Part --without spillover

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{document}
    \phantom{~}
    \begin{tabular}{{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.75\textwidth}}}
    \hline
    First column&Second column\\
    \hline
    abcd&\blindtext\\
    efgh&ijkl\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Second part--with spillover

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}
\phantom{~}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
First column&Second column\\
\hline
abcd&\blindtext\\
efgh&ijkl\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This should meet the requirement